# I’m so stuck…Databases…

Tags: java, sqlite, nullpointerexception, sql-update, android-cursorloader

I try to store the inserted data of my app to a database. So I chose SQLiteDatabase because that’s what
I had seen in my Nanodegree. Now I am to the point where I want to tap on an item from the ListView and
go the EditorActivity. When I code the **CursorLoader** in the EditorActivity.java to show the inserted data and to **update them**, the app crashes before it even starts…

The **editor activity** (here called MainActivity but here are the EditText fields):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private static final int EXISTING_CONTAINER_LOADER = 0;

DexamenesCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
private Uri mCurrentContainerUri;

 (...)

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
// Since the editor shows all container attributes, define a projection that contains
// all columns from the container table
String[] projection = {
        DexameniEntry._ID,
        DexameniEntry.COLUMN_a,
        DexameniEntry.COLUMN_b,
        DexameniEntry.COLUMN_c,};


// This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
return new CursorLoader(this,
        mCurrentContainerUri,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        null);

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data){

if (data.moveToFirst()) {
    if (data.moveToFirst()) {

        // Find the columns of pet attributes that we're interested in
        int aColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(DexameniEntry.COLUMN_a);
        int bColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(DexameniEntry.COLUMN_b);
        int cColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(DexameniEntry.COLUMN_c);


        // Extract out the value from the Cursor for the given column index
        int a = data.getInt(aColumnIndex);
        int b = data.getInt(bColumnIndex);
        int c = data.getInt(cColumnIndex);

        // Update the views on the screen with the values from the database
        mEditX1a.setText(Integer.toString(a));
        mEditX1b.setText(Integer.toString(b));
        mEditX1c.setText(Integer.toString(c));
    }

    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Here’s the **logcat**…

```
2018-11-28 15:51:44.853 26449-26470/com.example.android.deyalcalculator 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.android.deyalcalculator, PID: 26449
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing 
doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:111)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:515)
at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
 2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
 2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: 
 PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
 2018-11-28 15:51:44.891 26449-26449/com.example.android.deyalcalculator E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

I don’t know how to solve this issue. I don’t even know if SQLiteDatabase is the best choice to be honest
because I want the app to **store data** of a company’s measurements of water quality and **produce graphs** (like in a Stocks related app) over a long period of time (Graph of week’s measurement, month, year)…

Does anyone have any ideas about the solution of the spesific problem or in general a better way to store such kind of data?Please…(I’m tired and desperate from compiling lol)

Comment: You are asking about several things here.  Do you want help with your SQLite configuration, or do you want recommendations for your database design?

Comment: Where is your definition of `mCurrentContainerUri`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen primarily I ask how to fix the app crash..But if you have any idea on this, I'd like to know also what is the optimal way to implement these functions in such a way (store data, produce graphs with them)...

Answer (score -1):

It seems this field is mCurrentContainerUri is null value or not initialized .

```
if you see the source code for the class com.android.internal.util.Preconditions
```

you can see at line 111

```
/**
 * Ensures that an object reference passed as a parameter to the calling
 * method is not null.
 *
 * @param reference an object reference
 * @return the non-null reference that was validated
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
 */
public static @NonNull <T> T checkNotNull(final T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
}
```

in your case uri is null and somewhere it the checkNotNull method is called , check if the uri is null , hence there by null pointer exception thrown.

Comment: ok thank you...So I have to assign to mCurrentContainerUri the specific Uri of the list item clicked on. Could you help me with writing this in code?

Comment: no problem dalmation . first try assigning the value and let me know . if still doesnt work create a git project and share the url I will take a look.